# How to retrieve row numbers based on element repetition in xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Input is in the following format :

```
<imageLink>
    <url colNumber="1">aa</url>
    <imageTypeCode colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>
    <languageCode colNumber="3">en</languageCode>
    <languageCode colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
</imageLink>
<imageLink>
    <url colNumber="1">bb</url>
    <imageTypeCode colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>
    <languageCode colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
</imageLink>
```

Output format is as follows:

```
<imageLink rowNum="1">
    <url rowNum="1" colNumber="1">aa</url>
    <imageTypeCode rowNum="1" colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>
    <languageCode rowNum="1" colNumber="3">en</languageCode>
    <languageCode rowNum="2" colNumber="3">en1</languageCode>
</imageLink>
<imageLink rowNum="3">
    <url rowNum="3" colNumber="1">bb</url>
    <imageTypeCode rowNum="3" colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>
    <languageCode rowNum="3" colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
</imageLink>
```

This output is further then added to Excel format. How do I retrieve the row numbers exactly as shown in the output format?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way is to compute the attribute `rowNum` for the first `imageLink` and its children and then to take the maximum + 1 as the start value for the next sibling:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/*">
        <xsl:param name="row" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="copy" as="element()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="rowNum" select="$row"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates>
                    <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$copy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="row" select="max($copy/*/@rowNum) + 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/*/*">
        <xsl:param name="row"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:integer">
                <xsl:number/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:attribute name="rowNum" select="$row - 1 + $index"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*, node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms

```
<root>
    <imageLink>

        <url colNumber="1">aa</url>

        <imageTypeCode colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>

        <languageCode colNumber="3">en</languageCode>

        <languageCode colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
    </imageLink>
    <imageLink>

        <url colNumber="1">bb</url>

        <imageTypeCode colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>

        <languageCode colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
    </imageLink>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
   <imageLink rowNum="1">
      <url rowNum="1" colNumber="1">aa</url>
      <imageTypeCode rowNum="1" colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>
      <languageCode rowNum="1" colNumber="3">en</languageCode>
      <languageCode rowNum="2" colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
   </imageLink>
   <imageLink rowNum="3">
      <url rowNum="3" colNumber="1">bb</url>
      <imageTypeCode rowNum="3" colNumber="2">PRODUCT_IMAGE</imageTypeCode>
      <languageCode rowNum="3" colNumber="3">fr</languageCode>
   </imageLink>
</root>
```

Comment: yeah this works exactly as you say but i tried it using for the follwing process it does not work :

Comment: Please edit your question and show and explain how complex the input can get and which result you want for the new sample you have.

Comment: <xsl:apply-templates select=".//*[not()]"> this is throwing error

Comment: Static error at char 5 in {.//*[not()]} in expression in xsl:apply-templates/@select on line 23 column 59 of export.xsl:
  XPST0017: System function not() cannot be called with zero arguments
Static error at char 8 in {root/*//} in pattern in xsl:template/@match on line 34 column 36 of export.xsl:
  XTSE0340: Unexpected token "<eof>" at start of expression
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation

Comment: If you can have descendants and not only child elements then change `<xsl:apply-templates><xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>...` to `<xsl:apply-templates select=".//*[not(*)]"><xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>...` and `xsl:template match="root/*/*"` to `xsl:template match="root/*//"`.

Comment: Sorry, see the recent comment with corrected code snippets.

Comment: Static error at char 8 in {root/*//} in pattern in xsl:template/@match on line 31 column 36 of export.xsl:
  XTSE0340: Unexpected token "<eof>" at start of expression
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation

Still getting error.

@Martin

Comment: The pattern is meant to be `root/*//*` to cover any descendant elements of the children of the root element.

Comment: i have edited the required format in question for more better understanding can you provide me a solution ?

Comment: If you need or want to edit your question then do that. But please refrain from editing my answer to provide changed requirements.